# How to set autofill for username in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, authentication

I have a piece of code that will not, for the life of me, set autofill for the username. It will autofill the password for some reason. Im hoping someone will know a short easy solution. I know there is but ive tried "username" and "email" for the field and nothing pops up. The "admin@dw.com" (made up email for testing purposes) wont fill the email field... Thank you in advance! I have attached short code and an image below:

```
<Input
          type="email"
          id="email"
          autocomplete
          value={Email}
          onChange={(text) => setEmail(text.target.value)}
          placeholder="Ex: JohnSmith@gmail.com"
        />
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean bu autofill the suggestions that a plugin gives you or?

Answer (score 0):

here are two solutions:

1) get rid of value in your input and use placeholder or

2) comment out placeholder and use the js

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
//input[0].value ="john@abc.com";
```

```html
<Input
          type="email"
          id="email"    
          
          placeholder="johny@anc.com"
              
        />
```